# Why do I get several errors using typedef in C?

Tags: c, typedef

I am trying to define `TrapLevelLayout` as the equivalent of a two-dimentional array of `TrapSquare` defined above. This is my snippet of code:

```
typedef struct TrapSquare {
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
    
    TrapBlock **blocks;
    uint8_t count;
} TrapSquare; //Definition of type TrapSquare

typedef (TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout; // Definition of TrapLevelLayout
                                              // as an array of TrapSquare
```

This code produces the following warning and errors:

```
./Headers/TrapTypes.h:111:21: error: expected ')'
typedef (TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout;
                   ^
./Headers/TrapTypes.h:111:9: note: to match this '('
typedef (TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout;
        ^
./Headers/TrapTypes.h:111:10: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
typedef (TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout;
~~~~~~~  ^
./Headers/TrapTypes.h:111:10: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int' vs 'struct TrapSquare')
./Headers/TrapTypes.h:109:3: note: previous definition is here
} TrapSquare;
  ^
./Headers/TrapTypes.h:111:24: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
typedef (TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout;
                      ^
                      ;
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with my code?

Comment: @Hobbes, you should try to remove the brackets from the definition of TrapLevelLayout?

Comment: `typedef TrapSquare ( TrapLevelLayout )[32][18];` - parsed according to spiral rule

Comment: @Progxy It looks like they were simply misplaced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there are few issues:

1. Using same name as typedef `TrapSquare` in structure definition
2. `typedef (TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout;` wrong declaration

```
typedef struct _TrapSquare {
    uint8_t x;
    uint8_t y;
    TrapBlock **blocks;
    uint8_t count;
} TrapSquare; //Definition of type TrapSquare

TrapSquare TrapLevelLayout [32][18];  // Definition of TrapLevelLayout
                                      // as an array of TrapSquare
```

Comment: 1. is completely irrelevant and does not change anything. 2. is the correct answer.

Comment: This is working, tysm! I'll accept your answer asap

Comment: @mch: Thanks! But I want to keep my answer as it is though, for future visitors to understand it by referring your comment as well :-)

Comment: typedef is not needed again  here `typedef TrapSquare TrapLevelLayout[32][18]`, this will do `TrapSquare TrapLevelLayout[32][18]`

Comment: @Hackaholic thank you for this! For some reason, the syntax ```typedef TrapSquare TrapLevelLayout [32][18]``` doesn't really resonate with me...

Comment: @Hackaholic modified the answer as per your comments, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This answer is an alternative/extension to the [correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74938046/4989451).

You can use a popular `typeof` extension (a feature in C23):

```
typedef typeof(TrapSquare[32][18]) TrapLevelLayout;
```